# List of angular 2 in built services?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services

I am new to **angular 2** and am looking for a complete **list of all the in built services** that are available in it (like angular 1 -$http,$location etc).
A typescript doc would be incredibly helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `providers` in each of the modules listed in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/#!?query=module